# Formatting a HTML Container

Tags: javascript, html, format

I am asking how to remove the space thats present within the container from the heading to the top of the container and from the bottom of container to the tops of the buttons. Thanks

Attatched are images to support

CSS

[image: html code]

Output

[image: code within chrome]

Comment: This does not appear to be Java as your tags suggest. Java != Javascript

Comment: Please never show pictures of code. Copy the actual code into your question. Additionally, while we do want to see the CSS, we'd also want to see the related HTML for this question as well.

Answer (score 0):

That's the [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin) (the space around the outside of an element) and [padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding) (the space around the interior of an element) that all [block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) have. You can remove them with CSS.  Margins and paddings are important concepts to understand as they are parts of the [CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model), which determines layout of elements on your web page.

In the example below (in the first `fieldset`), you'll notice that there is no extra space above and below the `<h1>` or around the inside edges of the `fieldset` like there is in the second example:

```css
#test1 { padding:0; } /* No space around inside edge of first fieldset */
#test1 h1 { margin-top:0; margin-bottom:0; } /* No space above/below first <h1> */
```

```html
<fieldset id="test1">
  <div>some content</div>
  <h1>Heading One</h1>
  <div>some content</div>
</fieldset>
<br>
<fieldset id="test2">
  <div>some content</div>
  <h1>Heading One</h1>
  <div>some content</div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: @BryanMarquick Please up vote all answers that were helpful and mark the answer that solved your problem as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top-left of that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the margin to 0, wherever you want to remove the space between the two elements. You can use,

```
margin-top:0; 
margin-bottom:0; 
margin-left:0; 
margin-right:0;
```

to change the margin of different sides.